# Interacting with IE drop downs with VBA. (Send Keys not working) (getElementbytag not working)

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, sendkeys

I have tried 10-20 variations of the code below:

```vb
If dropDown <> "" Then
    Dim post As Object
    Application.Wait Now + #12:00:04 AM#
    Set post = ie.document.getElementById("swapUser")
    Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
    Set dropOptions = ie.document.getElementsbytagname("select")
    Set elem = ie.document.getElementsbytagname("option")

    For Each elem In dropOptions
        On Error Resume Next

        With post
            .Click
            .Focus
            .Expand   

            Do While elem.Value <> dropDown 'dropDown is the desired value'
                Debug.Print elem.Value
                Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
            Loop
        End With
    Next elem

    Application.Wait Now + #12:00:02 AM#
    Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
End If
```

To interact with this dropdown portion of a webpage:

```html
<select id="swapUser" name="swapUser" style="width:250px;margin-left:20px;margin-top: 10px;">
    <option value="831882,Clinic">BRiO Utah HH</option>
    <option value="897165,Clinic">24 Hour Home Care</option>
    <option value="776915,Clinic">Brio Idaho Home Health</option>
    <option value="776913,Clinic">Home Health</option>
</select>
```

It just does not want to arrow through the options. I can do it manually.

UPDATE

```
        post.Focus
            For Each Children In post
            If Children.Value = dropDown Then
            Children.Selected = True



            End If
            Next
```

This seems to correctly highlight and change to the correct instance. I cannot get .click, .activate, .fireevent "onchange" or any other "activation" to work from this point though :(

found this as well.

[back end of kinnser website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJM34.png)

Comment: Would it be possible to share the URL? There might be a more efficient way than actually interacting with the dropdown menu..

Comment: First of all you must remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line hides **all** error messages until the end of your code, but the errors still occur. You just cannot see them. If you don't see errors you cannot fix them, if you don't fix them of course your code cannot work properly. Remove it and [edit] your question to tell which errors you get. • Second `SendKeys` is the most non-reliable approach to do something I know. Avoid that at any cost. • Go through your code step by step (using F8) to analyze each step and to analyze your variable values in the VB-Editor to get closer to your issue.

Comment: @StavrosJon unfortunately I can't share the URL or the site contents past the page code. I'd have to give credentials and I'd get an butt kicking.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I removed On Error Resume Next :D I also got rid of send keys and replaced the interaction with this:     `post.Focus
            For Each Children In post
            If Children.Value = dropDown Then
            Children.Selected = True
            
            
            
            End If
            Next` this seems to work as far as selecting the correct child. I cannot get an activation or click to work though. I have tried fireevents "onchange" to no avail

Comment: @Dflanders Actually it is unclear to me what you are trying to do. And what does *"it just does not want to arrow through the options"* mean? What do you expect from your code versus what did it actually do?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Sorry for my communication issues. I am new to this lol. So the purpose of the swap user element is to change the current user role on the website I am interacting with. I am able to highlight the correct user (designated by the dropDown variable in my excel sheet) but I cannot invoke the resulting javascript that actually changes the user role. The "arrow through" is now null and void as I am now using children of the swapuser element. I am not trying to initiate that action so it will swap users. .click does not work. fireevent onchange does not work. I have been up and down the options